# How to mock only one method using Sinon?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, qunit, sinon

I've got a single method in my namespace that I'd like to [mock](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks), but I'd prefer that all the others work normally.  Is it possible to have sinon mock a specific method while leaving the others the same?

My understanding is I'm not looking for a spy because I want to assert that the mock was called with specific parameters.

Here's my code in CoffeeScript:

```
root.targeting.handleUnitsAttack = (gameState) ->
  units = gameState.heroes.concat(gameState.badGuys)
  for source in units
    for target in units
      gameState = root.targeting.sourceAttackTarget(gameState, source, target)
  gameState
```

I'd like to mock `sourceAttackTarget` and verify that its arguments are specific values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is one of the most common uses cases for sinon@2, but I believe that what you are looking for is neither a mock nor a spy, but instead a stub.

See: https://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.4.1/stubs/

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "foo");
//do your assertions
stub.restore(); //back to normal now.
```

This will allow you to create a default function that replaces `object.foo()`.

From your question, however, it sounds like a no-op stub function is not what you are after, and instead want to override it with a custom function of your own:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "foo", function customFoo() { /* ... */ });
//do your assertions
stub.restore(); //back to normal now.
```

HTH!

---

EDIT:

#### How to stub a single function:

The following stubs `object.sourceAttackTarget()`

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "sourceAttackTarget", function sourceAttackTargetCustom(gameState, source, target) {
    //do assertions on gameState, source, and target
    // ...
    return customReturn;
});
//do any further assertions
stub.restore(); //back to normal now.
```

#### How to stub a function to test for particular parameters

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "sourceAttackTarget");
stub.withArgs(1, "foo", "bar").returns("correctTarget");
stub.returns("wrongTarget");
var output = object.sourceAttackTarget(gameState, source, target);
equal(output, "correctTarget", 'sourceAttackTarget invoked with the right arguments');
//do any further assertions
stub.restore(); //back to normal now.
```

(Update)

There is also `.calledWith()` and `.calledWithMatch()`, which I just found out about. Could also prove quite useful for these sorts of tests.

#### How to mock just one method for an object:

"Mocks come with built-in expectations that may fail your test. Thus, they enforce implementation details. The rule of thumb is: if you wouldn’t add an assertion for some specific call, don’t mock it. Use a stub instead. In general you should never have more than one mock (possibly with several expectations) in a single test." - [source](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks)

... so for the question asked above, a mock is **not** the right thing to use, and a stub is the appropriate choice. That being said, one of the scenarios can be tested easily with a mock, and that is the expectation that a method has been called with a particular set of arguments.

```
var mock = sinon.mock(object);
mock.expects("sourceAttackTarget").withArgs(1, "foo", "bar");
object.sourceAttackTarget(gameState, source, target);
mock.verify();
```

Comment: I actually want to verify things at the end.  I want to verify that the mock was called with specific parameters.

Comment: and in fact, I actually want to control what the mocked method returns too.  I feel like I want everything possible, although my code is pretty simple.  I'll edit my question to show it.

Comment: If you want to verify that the method was called with specific parameters, then a simple stub will suffice. Otherwise, use the second option, where you add the custom function, do your assertions within the custom function for the expected parameters, and then also return a the value that you wish.

Comment: Can you update your example showing me how to do that?

Comment: "If you want to verify that the method was called with specific parameters, then a simple stub will suffice."  Can you show that part, too?

Comment: And I'd also appreciate it if you showed how to mock a single function because others will come back here one day with a valid reason to know how to do that and want to see the answer.

Comment: OK, just edited to add how to stub a function to test that particular parameters were used.

Comment: ... and just added a section on mocks - with a disclaimer, because mocks are not the right thing to do for what you have asked.

Comment: A *key* to my question is what do I pass in for `object` in this case?  Is it `root.targeting`?

Comment: Yes, `object` is the variable which contains the function which you wish to stub. In this case, that would be `root.targeting`. What sinon does under the hood is `var methodBeforeStubbing = object[methodName];`

Comment: Updatred answer to add `.calledWIth()` and `.calledWithMatch()`

Comment: The answer is out-dated. The correct way to use sinon stub has become `stub(obj, 'meth').callsFake(fn)`

Answer (score 3):

Starting with sinon@3.0.0, the

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method", func);
```

has been removed. One should rather use:

```
stub(object, "method").callsFake(func)
```

> ```
> stub.callsFake(fakeFunction);
> Makes the stub call the provided fakeFunction when invoked.
>
> var myObj = {};
> myObj.prop = function propFn() {
>     return 'foo';
> };
>
> sinon.stub(myObj, 'prop').callsFake(function fakeFn() {
>     return 'bar';
> });
>
> myObj.prop(); // 'bar'
> ```

Source: [sinonjs docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.1.1/stubs/)

Answer (score 0):

```
const { foo } = require('../some.js');
const service = { foo };
const stub = sinon.stub(service, "foo");
```

It normally expects an object where `foo` needs to be part of it. Simply declare an object by yourself, add the function as a property, and then use it while stubbing.